# Item information for 4PL under IRT

Tags: item-response-theory

What is the item information curve for 4PL model under item response theory (IRT)? the information of 3PL has quite a neat form:

[image: 3PL information]

But what it is like if I add parameter of carelessness "d"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same, but like the 3PL model you get progressively less information in the extreme ends of $\theta$ due to the upper/lower bound parameters. It has the form:

$$I(\theta) = \frac{a^2 (p(\theta) - c)^2 (d - p(\theta))^2}{(d-c)^2 p(\theta)(1-p(\theta))}$$
in case that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!